# Copying All Settings Of One Composition in AE

Tags: after-effects, adobe

I want to copy the whole settings of the composition to the other, all keyframes, transition points, 3d layer etc. In Adobe After Effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do in one step, it is only possible to **duplicate compositions**:

- Select the composition (*Import Footage Panel*)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or go to *Composition > Duplicate Composition*)
- As (almost) everywhere in AE, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the selected composition to *rename the duplicate*

---

When you need to **copy the properties of a layer**:

- Select the *Layer*
- Click on the tiny Triangle <kbd>></kbd> left beside the layers name to open up the properties
- Select *Transform, Effects or Mask*
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Switch to the *Second Composition*
- Select the *Layer*
- Set the *playhead* to the animation *start frame* (first keyframe)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to *overwrite all properties* and *insert all copied keyframes*

To check the result, press <kbd>U</kbd> on the *Layer*, this will open up all animated properties of the layer.

Note: Copying the **same properties of different layers** is also possible by *selecting multiple layers*, *open up the properties simultaneously*, and select them by *holding down* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

---

Related: [After Effects: Shortcut for showing all transforming properties of a layer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17326/after-effects-shortcut-for-showing-all-transforming-properties-of-a-layer)